# Why this Mayavi animation in python is executed differently in Pycharm Run and in Console and in PyCharm Debug?

Tags: pycharm, garbage-collection, mayavi

I would like to ask for ways on how I can investigate this problem, specifically, if there is an inherent problem with the function below or a problem with PyCharm.

I am doing a 3D simulation and plotting the results with Mayavi. I am using PyCharm.

My function for the animation (below) is supposed to make an animation with 10000 frames, but the software stops executing at a specific iteration depending on how it is executed. When I run it, it stops at iteration 8, when I run on the debugger, it stops at iteration 4318 and when I run on the console, it stops at iteration 5000. By 'stops running', I don't mean an error, it simply stops at a given line.

```
def animates(bond_matrix):
x, y, z, scalars, connections = particle_coordinates(bond_matrix)
l = mlab.points3d(10*x, 10*y, 10*z, scale_factor=5)
l.mlab_source.dataset.lines = np.array(connections)
tube = mlab.pipeline.tube(l, tube_radius=1, tube_sides=3)
mlab.pipeline.surface(tube, color=(0.8, 0.8, 0))

# Now animate the data.
ms = l.mlab_source

@mlab.animate(delay=10)
def anim():
    mlab.gcf()
    i = 0
    while(i < 10000):
        print(i)
        x, y , z, s, c = particle_coordinates(bond_matrix)
        ms.set(x=10*x, y=10*y, z=10*z)
        update_system(bond_matrix)
        i += 1
        yield
anim()
mlab.show()
```

On the other hand, the script below runs perfectly normal:

```
@mlab.animate(delay = 10)
def updateAnimation():
    t = 0.0
    for i in range(10000):
        print(i)
        ball.mlab_source.set(x = np.cos(t), y = np.sin(t), z = 0)
        t += 0.1
        yield

ball = mlab.points3d(np.array(1.), np.array(0.), np.array(0.))

updateAnimation()
mlab.show()
```

In this software, bond_matrix is a numpy array and particle coordinates reads the coordinates from it. The specific iteration in which it fails depends on the size of this matrix, for small matrixes I don't see the error and the larger the matrix the sooner the simulation stops. update_system is a function that modifies this matrix but the plotting problem occurs even when the matrix is kept the same in all frames.

When I run the code in these 3 different ways, I use the same version of python for all conditions in the same virtual environment.

What I thought:

- Memory leak, but I checked the memory usage of PyCharm and Python and it looks normal.
- A problem with the update_system function, but it works through all interactions when the results are not being animated.

What I researched:

- Running on the debugger and console run the script line by line I think that could be why they differ comparing to when the entire script is interpreted, but why are debugger and console different? And which part of the function makes it work differently when it is run line by line?
- This could be a problem of using PyQt4 or PyQt5, although I used both and the problem persists, I think the problem is related to the PyQt version because if I set the PyQt compatibility to 'Auto', the software stops running at different iterations. Am I using Mayavi and PyQt wrong or is this a PyCharm bug? At the same time, why this problems seems to appear only on large animations, but doesn't give any error?

Thank you for any insight.

PyCharm version 11.0.7
Python version = 3.7
PyQt 5.15.0
mayavi 4.7.2.dev()
traitsui 7.0.0
wxPython 4.1.0

EDIT: I solved this issue by adding a line gc.collect(generation=1) in the code, but could someone please explain why PyCharm garbage collection is not working as expected in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the garbage management. The function could run normally by using the garbage collection module:

```
@mlab.animate(delay=10)
def anim():
    mlab.gcf()
    i = 0
    while(i < 10000):
        print(i)
        x, y , z, s, c = particle_coordinates(bond_matrix)
        ms.set(x=10 * x, y=10 * y, z=10 * z)
        update_system(bond_matrix)
        i += 1
        yield
        gc.collect(generation=1)
anim()
mlab.show()
```